# SSRS: Can I display more than one table using the same dataset?

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-tablix

I have a report in HTML where, depending on the organization, can display more that one table, which was relatively easy in HTML. Now, I'm writting the same report in SSRS.

Is there a way I can use something like a repeater (like in ASP.NET) table can be repeated while individual table can have it's own data to display.

I don't really know where to start. Maybe I could have like 10 table pointing to similar slightly modified dataset, and hide the table when there is no data.

Thanks for helping

## EDIT

The query returns something like this:

```
ID | Organization | Total | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5
-------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Accounting   | 10    | 2    | 1    | 3    | 0    |  4
-------------------------------------------------------------
2  | Production   | 15    | 7    | 0    | 3    | 1    |  4
```

Now the report should look something like this

```
         Accounting
-------------------------------
| col1            | 2 (20.00%) |  
--------------------------------
| col2            | 1 (10.00%) |  
--------------------------------
| col3            | 3 (30.00%) |    
--------------------------------
| col4            | 0 (0.00%)  |   
--------------------------------
| col5            | 4 (40.00%) |     
--------------------------------
```

So a table will be drown for every row.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.

Say you want to have a table for each value in Field A, you can create a table using fields B-X, then place this table into a cell in another table, which is using the same dataset and is row-grouped by Field A. This will essentially provide a filter for each of your sub-tables.

The sub-tables will auto-size to the width and height of the cell in your "super-table", but this can be avoided (if desired) by placing the sub-table inside of a rectangle and placing the rectangle into the super-table. You'll then find the rectangle to be resizable, and the rest of the cell can be padded out with other rectangles.

To create the appearance of multiple tables, you can play around with borders, etc., so that the super-table is no longer visible.

Xml for the data you provided (body only):

```
<Body>
  <ReportItems>
    <Textbox Name="textbox1">
      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
      <Paragraphs>
        <Paragraph>
          <TextRuns>
            <TextRun>
              <Value>Report1</Value>
              <Style>
                <FontFamily>Tahoma</FontFamily>
                <FontSize>20pt</FontSize>
                <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                <Color>SteelBlue</Color>
              </Style>
            </TextRun>
          </TextRuns>
          <Style />
        </Paragraph>
      </Paragraphs>
      <rd:DefaultName>textbox1</rd:DefaultName>
      <Height>0.36in</Height>
      <Width>5in</Width>
      <Style>
        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
      </Style>
    </Textbox>
    <Tablix Name="Tablix2">
<TablixBody>
  <TablixColumns>
    <TablixColumn>
      <Width>0.41667in</Width>
    </TablixColumn>
    <TablixColumn>
      <Width>2.19792in</Width>
    </TablixColumn>
    <TablixColumn>
      <Width>0.39583in</Width>
    </TablixColumn>
  </TablixColumns>
  <TablixRows>
    <TablixRow>
      <Height>0.25in</Height>
      <TablixCells>
        <TablixCell>
          <CellContents>
            <Textbox Name="Textbox29">
              <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
              <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
              <Paragraphs>
                <Paragraph>
                  <TextRuns>
                    <TextRun>
                      <Value />
                      <Style />
                    </TextRun>
                  </TextRuns>
                  <Style />
                </Paragraph>
              </Paragraphs>
              <rd:DefaultName>Textbox29</rd:DefaultName>
              <Style>
                <Border>
                  <Style>None</Style>
                </Border>
                <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
              </Style>
            </Textbox>
          </CellContents>
        </TablixCell>
        <TablixCell>
          <CellContents>
            <Textbox Name="Textbox31">
              <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
              <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
              <Paragraphs>
                <Paragraph>
                  <TextRuns>
                    <TextRun>
                      <Value />
                      <Style />
                    </TextRun>
                  </TextRuns>
                  <Style />
                </Paragraph>
              </Paragraphs>
              <rd:DefaultName>Textbox31</rd:DefaultName>
              <Style>
                <Border>
                  <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                  <Style>None</Style>
                </Border>
                <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
              </Style>
            </Textbox>
          </CellContents>
        </TablixCell>
        <TablixCell>
          <CellContents>
            <Textbox Name="Textbox35">
              <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
              <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
              <Paragraphs>
                <Paragraph>
                  <TextRuns>
                    <TextRun>
                      <Value />
                      <Style />
                    </TextRun>
                  </TextRuns>
                  <Style />
                </Paragraph>
              </Paragraphs>
              <rd:DefaultName>Textbox35</rd:DefaultName>
              <Style>
                <Border>
                  <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                  <Style>None</Style>
                </Border>
                <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
              </Style>
            </Textbox>
          </CellContents>
        </TablixCell>
      </TablixCells>
    </TablixRow>
    <TablixRow>
      <Height>1.41667in</Height>
      <TablixCells>
<TablixCell>
  <CellContents>
    <Textbox Name="Organization">
      <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
      <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
      <Paragraphs>
        <Paragraph>
          <TextRuns>
            <TextRun>
              <Value />
              <Style />
            </TextRun>
          </TextRuns>
          <Style />
        </Paragraph>
      </Paragraphs>
      <rd:DefaultName>Organization</rd:DefaultName>
      <Style>
        <Border>
          <Style>None</Style>
        </Border>
        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
      </Style>
    </Textbox>
  </CellContents>
</TablixCell>
<TablixCell>
  <CellContents>
    <Tablix Name="Tablix1">
      <TablixBody>
        <TablixColumns>
          <TablixColumn>
            <Width>1.09896in</Width>
          </TablixColumn>
          <TablixColumn>
            <Width>1.09896in</Width>
          </TablixColumn>
        </TablixColumns>
        <TablixRows>
          <TablixRow>
            <Height>0.23611in</Height>
            <TablixCells>
              <TablixCell>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="Organization1">
                    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>=Fields!Organization.Value</Value>
                            <Style />
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style>
                          <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                        </Style>
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>Organization1</rd:DefaultName>
                    <Style>
                      <Border>
                        <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                      </Border>
                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                    </Style>
                  </Textbox>
                  <ColSpan>2</ColSpan>
                </CellContents>
              </TablixCell>
              <TablixCell />
            </TablixCells>
          </TablixRow>
          <TablixRow>
            <Height>0.23611in</Height>
            <TablixCells>
              <TablixCell>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="col1">
                    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>col1</Value>
                            <Style />
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style />
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>col1</rd:DefaultName>
                    <Style>
                      <Border>
                        <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                      </Border>
                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                    </Style>
                  </Textbox>
                </CellContents>
              </TablixCell>
              <TablixCell>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="col6">
                    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>=Fields!col1.Value</Value>
                            <Style />
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style />
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>col1</rd:DefaultName>
                    <Style>
                      <Border>
                        <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                      </Border>
                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                    </Style>
                  </Textbox>
                </CellContents>
              </TablixCell>
            </TablixCells>
          </TablixRow>
          <TablixRow>
            <Height>0.23611in</Height>
            <TablixCells>
              <TablixCell>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="col2">
                    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>col2</Value>
                            <Style />
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style />
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>col2</rd:DefaultName>
                    <Style>
                      <Border>
                        <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                      </Border>
                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                    </Style>
                  </Textbox>
                </CellContents>
              </TablixCell>
              <TablixCell>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="col21">
                    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>=Fields!col2.Value</Value>
                            <Style />
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style />
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>col21</rd:DefaultName>
                    <Style>
                      <Border>
                        <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                      </Border>
                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                    </Style>
                  </Textbox>
                </CellContents>
              </TablixCell>
            </TablixCells>
          </TablixRow>
          <TablixRow>
            <Height>0.23611in</Height>
            <TablixCells>
              <TablixCell>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="col3">
                    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>col3</Value>
                            <Style />
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style />
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>col3</rd:DefaultName>
                    <Style>
                      <Border>
                        <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                      </Border>
                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                    </Style>
                  </Textbox>
                </CellContents>
              </TablixCell>
              <TablixCell>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="col31">
                    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>=Fields!col3.Value</Value>
                            <Style />
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style />
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>col31</rd:DefaultName>
                    <Style>
                      <Border>
                        <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                      </Border>
                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                    </Style>
                  </Textbox>
                </CellContents>
              </TablixCell>
            </TablixCells>
          </TablixRow>
          <TablixRow>
            <Height>0.23611in</Height>
            <TablixCells>
              <TablixCell>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="col4">
                    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>col4</Value>
                            <Style />
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style />
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>col4</rd:DefaultName>
                    <Style>
                      <Border>
                        <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                      </Border>
                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                    </Style>
                  </Textbox>
                </CellContents>
              </TablixCell>
              <TablixCell>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="Textbox15">
                    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>=Fields!col4.Value</Value>
                            <Style />
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style />
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>Textbox15</rd:DefaultName>
                    <Style>
                      <Border>
                        <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                      </Border>
                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                    </Style>
                  </Textbox>
                </CellContents>
              </TablixCell>
            </TablixCells>
          </TablixRow>
          <TablixRow>
            <Height>0.23611in</Height>
            <TablixCells>
              <TablixCell>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="col5">
                    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>col5</Value>
                            <Style />
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style />
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>col5</rd:DefaultName>
                    <Style>
                      <Border>
                        <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                      </Border>
                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                    </Style>
                  </Textbox>
                </CellContents>
              </TablixCell>
              <TablixCell>
                <CellContents>
                  <Textbox Name="Textbox18">
                    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                    <Paragraphs>
                      <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                          <TextRun>
                            <Value>=Fields!col5.Value</Value>
                            <Style />
                          </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style />
                      </Paragraph>
                    </Paragraphs>
                    <rd:DefaultName>Textbox18</rd:DefaultName>
                    <Style>
                      <Border>
                        <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                        <Style>Solid</Style>
                      </Border>
                      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                    </Style>
                  </Textbox>
                </CellContents>
              </TablixCell>
            </TablixCells>
          </TablixRow>
        </TablixRows>
      </TablixBody>
      <TablixColumnHierarchy>
        <TablixMembers>
          <TablixMember />
          <TablixMember />
        </TablixMembers>
      </TablixColumnHierarchy>
      <TablixRowHierarchy>
        <TablixMembers>
          <TablixMember />
          <TablixMember />
          <TablixMember />
          <TablixMember />
          <TablixMember />
          <TablixMember />
        </TablixMembers>
      </TablixRowHierarchy>
      <DataSetName>DataSet1</DataSetName>
      <Style>
        <Border>
          <Style>None</Style>
        </Border>
      </Style>
    </Tablix>
  </CellContents>
</TablixCell>
        <TablixCell>
          <CellContents>
            <Textbox Name="Textbox36">
              <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
              <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
              <Paragraphs>
                <Paragraph>
                  <TextRuns>
                    <TextRun>
                      <Value />
                      <Style />
                    </TextRun>
                  </TextRuns>
                  <Style />
                </Paragraph>
              </Paragraphs>
              <rd:DefaultName>Textbox36</rd:DefaultName>
              <Style>
                <Border>
                  <Style>None</Style>
                </Border>
                <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
              </Style>
            </Textbox>
          </CellContents>
        </TablixCell>
      </TablixCells>
    </TablixRow>
  </TablixRows>
</TablixBody>
      <TablixColumnHierarchy>
        <TablixMembers>
          <TablixMember />
          <TablixMember />
          <TablixMember />
        </TablixMembers>
      </TablixColumnHierarchy>
      <TablixRowHierarchy>
        <TablixMembers>
          <TablixMember>
            <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
          </TablixMember>
          <TablixMember>
            <Group Name="Details">
              <GroupExpressions>
                <GroupExpression>=Fields!Organization.Value</GroupExpression>
              </GroupExpressions>
            </Group>
          </TablixMember>
        </TablixMembers>
      </TablixRowHierarchy>
      <DataSetName>DataSet1</DataSetName>
      <Top>0.36in</Top>
      <Height>1.66667in</Height>
      <Width>3.01042in</Width>
      <ZIndex>1</ZIndex>
      <Style>
        <Border>
          <Style>None</Style>
        </Border>
      </Style>
    </Tablix>
  </ReportItems>
  <Height>3.69667in</Height>
  <Style />
</Body>
```

The DataSet is:

```
<DataSets>
  <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
    <Query>
      <DataSourceName>DataSource1</DataSourceName>
      <CommandText>SELECT        1 AS ID, 'Accounting' AS Organization, 10 AS Total, 2 AS col1, 1 AS col2, 3 AS col3, 0 AS col4, 4 AS col5
UNION ALL
SELECT        2 AS Expr1, 'Production' AS Expr2, 15 AS Expr3, 7 AS Expr4, 0 AS Expr5, 3 AS Expr6, 1 AS Expr7, 4 AS Expr8</CommandText>
    </Query>
    <Fields>
      <Field Name="ID">
        <DataField>ID</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
      </Field>
      <Field Name="Organization">
        <DataField>Organization</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
      </Field>
      <Field Name="Total">
        <DataField>Total</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
      </Field>
      <Field Name="col1">
        <DataField>col1</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
      </Field>
      <Field Name="col2">
        <DataField>col2</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
      </Field>
      <Field Name="col3">
        <DataField>col3</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
      </Field>
      <Field Name="col4">
        <DataField>col4</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
      </Field>
      <Field Name="col5">
        <DataField>col5</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
      </Field>
    </Fields>
  </DataSet>
</DataSets>
```

Comment: Please see the complement of info that I think will help to picture the final result.

Comment: So Field A would be your 'Organization' Field, and you would build your sub-table using the other field, 'col1', etc., and then add that into the row grouping on the super-table. I've added some xml to my answer which builds your output.

Answer (score 0):

I would *unpivot* for this task as in the script below:

```
--Create the table and insert values as portrayed in the previous example.
CREATE TABLE pvt (VendorID int, Emp1 int, Emp2 int,
    Emp3 int, Emp4 int, Emp5 int);
GO
INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (1,4,3,5,4,4);
INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (2,4,1,5,5,5);
INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (3,4,3,5,4,4);
INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (4,4,2,5,5,4);
INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (5,5,1,5,5,5);
GO

SELECT * FROM pvt
--Unpivot the table.
SELECT VendorID, Employee, Orders
FROM 
   (SELECT VendorID, Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, Emp5
   FROM pvt) p
UNPIVOT
   (Orders FOR Employee IN 
      (Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, Emp5)
)AS unpvt;
GO
```

[image]

From: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx